# PHP | Input control statements do not do the job

Tags: php

I don't understand why I have implemented control instructions in my form that don't work, every time they record in the database all the behaviors that I don't want.

```
 /*ERRORI*/
    $nome_obbligatorio = "";
    $errore_nome = "";

    $cognome_obbligatorio = "";
    $errore_cognome = "";

    $password_obbligatoria = "";
    $due_psw_non_coincidono = "";
    $password_err_min_8_caratteri = "";
    $password_err_min_8_max_20_caratteri = "";
    $errore_password = "";

    $citta_obbligatorio = "";
    $errore_citta = "";

    $cap_obbligatorio = "";
    $errore_cap = "";
    $errore_cap_caratteri_speciali = "";

    $telefono_obbligatorio = "";
    $errore_telefono = "";

    $iban_obbligatorio = "";
    $iban_err_min_27_caratteri = "";

    /*FINE ERRORI*/

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        /*CAMPI FORM*/
        $nome = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
        $cognome = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['cognome']);
        $password = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $citta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['citta']);
        $cap = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['cap']);
        $telefono = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['telefono']);
        $iban = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['iban']);
        $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $confermaPassword = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['confermaPassword']);
        $indirizzo = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['indirizzo']);
        $indirizzo_txt = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['indirizzo_txt']);
        $civico = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['civico']);
        $codice_fiscale = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['codice_fiscale']);
        $categoria_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['categoria_richiesta']);


        /*FINE CAMPI FORM*/
        /*----------------------------------------------------*/


        if (empty($_POST["nome"])) {
            $nome_obbligatorio = "Nome è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if (!preg_match("~[0-9]+~", $nome)) {
                $errore_nome = "Il nome non può contenere numeri";
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST["cognome"])) {
            $cognome_obbligatorio = "Cognome è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if (!preg_match("~[0-9]+~", $cognome)) {
                $errore_cognome = "Il cognome non può contenere numeri";
            }
        }



        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $password_obbligatoria = "Password è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if( strlen($password ) < 8 )
            {
                $password_err_min_8_caratteri .= "La Password deve contenere almeno 8 caratteri";

            }

            if( strlen($password ) > 20 )
            {
                $password_err_min_8_max_20_caratteri .= "La Password può essere composta da 8 fino a 20 caratteri";
            }

            if( !preg_match("A(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[A-Z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[a-z])(?=[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*?[0-9])[-_a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}z", $password ) )
            {
                $errore_password .= "La Password deve contenere almeno una lettera maiuscola una minuscola e un numero";
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST["citta"])) {
            $citta_obbligatorio = "Città è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if (!preg_match("#\W+#", $citta)) {
                $errore_citta = "Città non può contenere caratteri speciali";
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST["cap"])) {
            $citta_obbligatorio = "CAP è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $cap ))
            {
                $errore_cap .= "Il CAP non può contenere lettere";
            }
            if( !preg_match("#\W+#", $cap ) )
            {
                $errore_cap_caratteri_speciali .= "Il CAP non può contenere caratteri speciali";
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST["telefono"])) {
            $telefono_obbligatorio = "Telefono è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {

            if( !preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $telefono ) )
            {
                $errore_telefono .= "Il telefono non può contenere lettere";
            }
        }


        if (empty($_POST["iban"])) {
            $iban_obbligatorio = "IBAN è un campo obbligatorio";
        } else {
            if( strlen($password ) < 27 )
            {
                $iban_err_min_27_caratteri .= "L' IBAN deve contenere almeno 27 caratteri";

            }

        }

        if ($password != $confermaPassword)
            $due_psw_non_coincidono = "Le due password non coincidono!";



        $CONTROLLA = mysqli_query($connessione,"SELECT email FROM collaboratori WHERE email='$email'");
        $SE_IL_RISULTATO_IMMESSO=mysqli_num_rows($CONTROLLA);

        if($SE_IL_RISULTATO_IMMESSO==0)
        {
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            $connessione->query("INSERT INTO collaboratori 
                        (
                            nome,
                            cognome,
                            email,
                            password,
                            citta,
                            indirizzo,
                            indirizzo_txt,
                            civico,
                            cap,
                            telefono,
                            codice_fiscale,
                            iban,
                            categoria_richiesta
                        ) 

                        VALUES 
                        (
                            '$nome', 
                            '$cognome',
                            '$email', 
                            '$hash',
                            '$citta',
                            '$indirizzo',
                            '$indirizzo_txt',
                            '$civico',
                            '$cap',
                            '$telefono',
                            '$codice_fiscale',
                            '$iban'
                        )");

            header("location: index.php?col_reg=Y");

        }

        else
        {
            $indirizzo_email_gia_registrato = 'Indirizzo email, già registrato' ;
        }
    }
```

for example the field 'nome' and 'cognome', the controls seem non-existent
I can't understand why they fail every time,thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Because you don't check if any of variables with errors are __not empty__

Comment: Use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: The password regex is not correct and shouldn't be used in this form. Besides the delimiter missing, currently it enforces that the password must begin with the letter `A` and ends with the letter `z`. The backslashes, which were originally in the regex you have copied, were there for a reason. Also, limiting the password to 20 makes no sense, why do you want to limit the user password in that way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set your error variables, but do not check them before you send the query. You have to write some `if()` statement before sending the SQL query checking if there were any errors before. One way to do this is to use an array and fill it with error messages:

```
$errors = array();
if (/*name is invalid */) {
    $errors[] = 'Your name is invalid.';
}
if (/*city is invalid */) {
    $errors[] = 'Your city is invalid.';
}
if (/*email already used */) {
    $errors[] = 'The email address is already being used.';
}
//...

// check if there were any validation errors above.
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    // deal with error messages like showing them with 'echo' and `foreach`
} else {
    // all fine, send the query.
}
```